# Decrypt message with errors

Tags: encryption, aes

Say I've got a message A and I encrypt it with AES using password P into my encrypted message B. During the Storage of B some bits flip. So I've got a message B' which is very similar to B.

If I decrypt B' using the correct P will I get a decrypt massage A' which is similar to A?

Answer (score 3):

This really depends on the [mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) that you used. AES is a block cipher. So the actual AES algorithm is only defined for blocks of 128-bit. Everything else is the mode.

For example:

For **ECB** AES is executed for every block separately. This means that only those blocks differ which contain the flipped bits. But since AES is strong the degree they differ is huge (on average 64-bit or half the block size) <sup>1</sup>.

For **CBC** during encryption every plaintext block is XORed with the previous ciphertext block and then AES encrypted. The first block is XOR'ed with the "public" random IV. During decryption the AES decryption output is XOR'ed with the previous ciphertext block. So the blocks which contain the flipped bits are completely different between A and A' <sup>1</sup>.
The every block directly after every bad block has the same bits flipped which were introduced in B'. The block after that won't be changed. This means that when you decrypt B', A' matches with A excluding the blocks that contained flips and their directly succeeding blocks.

For **CTR** each plaintext bit is XOR'ed with a bit of the *key stream*, generated by encrypting a counter. For CTR therefore only one bit is affected.

To actually detect changes, you should use a MAC. Whether you use MAC on the plaintext or the ciphertext is up to you, but you should read this: [Should we MAC-then-encrypt or encrypt-then-MAC?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac). Or if you don't what to use a MAC, use an authenticated mode like GCM.

Those popular modes produce a plaintext that mostly isn't changed at all depending on the number of bit flips.

<sup>1</sup> A block cipher like AES is constructed in the way that a small change in the plaintext/ciphertext results in a big change in the ciphertext/plaintext after encryption/decryption.

Comment: Your statement regarding CBC is inaccurate. The block containing the bit flips will be completely scrambled. Any block immediately after a block with a bit flipped in it will decrypt to the plaintext with a bit flipped in the exact same position as the bit flip in the preceding block. This phenomenon is what permits CBC bit flipping attacks.

Comment: You're right, thanks. I disregarded the direction and thought about encryption. @AarynTonita

Comment: *On average* the *Hamming distance* between A and A' will indeed be 64 bit (half the block size). The small change does not have to result in a big change, but it is exceedingly likely for higher block sizes as the result of encryption/decryption should be indistinguishable from random.

Answer (score 1):

This is much more a question of the mode of operation than of the used block cipher. There are modes that will flip only a single bit (CTR), but there are also modes that will randomize all bits (BiIGE) which is supported by e.g. OpenSSL. The cryptographic property  of bit errors in ciphertext affecting the plaintext is called *error propagation*.

CTR is a counter mode. It creates a key stream that only uses the encryption function of the underlying block cipher - the decryption function is not used at all. This key stream may even be pre-calculated, or generated from a specific offset. The plaintext is simply XOR'ed with the key stream to produce the ciphertext. The decryption process is completely identical to the encryption process (double XOR with the same value is the identify function: a ^ k ^ k = a). So CTR by design only has one bit changed.

BiIGE on the other hand is specifically designed to produce a random plaintext if only one bit of ciphertext is changed. BiIGE stands for Bi-directional Infinite Garble Extension. In other words, it was *designed to propagate the error* and make sure that the first part of the plaintext is also garbled. BiIGE requires you to use the block cipher twice for each block of plaintext so it is not very efficient.

As for ECB, CBC, CFB, OFB all have different error propagation properties, but they are insubstantial so I won't even list them.

Usually however if you want to avoid changes in plaintext you simply protect the ciphertext against changes. This you can do by adding an authentication tag using a MAC or HMAC over the ciphertext and - if communicated over an insecure channel - the IV. There are also authenticated modes such as GCM and EAX that automatically create an authentication tag. MAC's, HMAC's and authenticated modes provide integrity and authenticity of the ciphertext.

GCM, EAX and CCM simply use CTR mode internally; the authentication tag already provides enough protection: the verification will fail before the plaintext is used (when applied properly).

Wikipedia puts it like this:

> Before the widespread use of message authentication codes and authenticated encryption, it was common to discuss the "error propagation" properties as a selection criterion for a mode of operation. It might be observed, for example, that a one-block error in the transmitted ciphertext would result in a one-block error in the reconstructed plaintext for ECB mode encryption, while in CBC mode such an error would affect two blocks.
>
> Some felt that such resilience was desirable in the face of random errors (e.g., line noise), while others argued that error correcting increased the scope for attackers to maliciously tamper with a message.
>
> However, when proper integrity protection is used, such an error will result (with high probability) in the entire message being rejected. If resistance to random error is desirable, error-correcting codes should be applied to the ciphertext before transmission.

It therefore won't surprise you much that BiIGE [is not used much](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9395/1172). It won't surprise you either that the code in most questions and even answers here on StackOverflow doesn't create an authentication tag even if it is really required to use one.